# Only Uninstall Button showing after Install an App from Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

The open button disappears after installing an app from the Google Play store. It's only showing uninstall button. 
I could not find my app listed on the device. 
I have tried it from different devices but the result is the same.

My current version is 34. It was ok in the previous version.
Here is the screenshot after installing the app

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about app stores are off-topic. See meta

Comment: did you remove the Launcher intent filter from activity in manifest?

Comment: No, The Launcher intent filter is in there on Manifest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You removed the intent filter from the Default Activity of your project, add it back to the appropriate Activity

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Nope Its on there on Manifest File

Comment: @FaisalMirza are you sure?

Comment: This can also happen if the intent filter is not valid, for example, more than one <action> or <category> in one intent filter

Comment: i also have same issue, in my case because i merge multiple intent filter into one. to solve just differentiate another intent filter with label and do not change MAIN and Launcher. just keep single name and single category.