# Not showing open option in google playstore only for my application

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Recently we published one new app in Playstore and we are noticing one issue. Whenever you install the app, after successful installation it is showing only uninstall option in Playstore but not showing open option.
We tried clearing cache restarting the phone everything but nothing seemed to be working. Can someone please help me here. Below is my part of manifest code

```
<application
android:name=".MyApplication"
android:allowBackup="false"
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
android:label="@string/global_label_APP_DISPLAY_NAME"
android:largeHeap="true"
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/Dsm.Theme.App"
tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"
tools:replace="android:label">
<activity
    android:name=".ui.SplashActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|locale"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:exported="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/Dsm.Theme.App.Fullscreen">
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
```

Comment: Please add your AndroidManifest.xml to your post so we can help you

Comment: Hi @mouaad Abdelghafour AITALI I eddited my question with part of my manifest file code can you please check the same.

Comment: Please add the full AndroidManifest or check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55512605/only-uninstall-button-showing-after-install-an-app-from-google-play-store

Comment: Hi @Mouaad Abdelghafour AITALI thanks for the reply, I don't see any issue with my intent filter as mentioned in the link given by you. Also the same app when we are installing as internal beta version it is showing open option, if there is some issue in manifest file then even in internal beta version of same also should not get the open option right?

Comment: Have you tried installing the app on a different device? I'm pretty sure the issue is in your manifest, setting `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in the `SplashScreen` it may cause the issue

Comment: @Mouaad Abdelghafour AITALI
 Yes we tried installing app in other phones and we can see same issue in other phones too. So you are telling android:launchMode="singleTask"  are you sure? This is my launcher Activity.

Comment: @Mouaad Abdelghafour AITALI
I don't think that is an issue because we have one more app published in playstore with same piece of code.

Comment: I'm asking you to provide the full android manifest, it may something wrong with your default activity (not the launcher activity)

Comment: @Mouaad Abdelghafour AITALI due to some reasons I cannot post the full code of my Manifest but SplashActivity is my default activity whose code I already provided. Is there any way you can help me here please.

Comment: Your SplashActivity is your LAUNCHER activity, not the default activity, which activity that's comes after the SplashActivity ? That's one it should be your DEFAULT activity

Comment: @Mouaad Abdelghafour AITALI I tried below steps which I got from Playstore team and I dont see that issue anymore. Do you think this is Manifest issue?

Please go to device main settings >> Tap on Apps >> Tap on Google Play store >> Tap on 3 dots on top right corner of the screen >> Tap Uninstall updates >> Tap OK.